# Extract sub-directory name based on pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a list of paths stored in a shell variable `tmp` for example:

```
/abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar
/abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S2_L001_I1.tar
/abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar
/abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar
/abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R2.tar
/abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar
```

I want to create new directories based on the matching patterns from the paths. In the above example, I want to create directories `ZRT834_9` and `ZRT207_1` and create soft links for the `tar` files into their corresponding directories.

My output should be something like: `ZRT834_9` directory having `S1_L001_R1.tar`, `S2_L001_I1.tar`, and `S1_L001_I2.tar`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Will all of the tar file names be unique (at least with respect to their destination directories)? If not, what is supposed to happen if two or more files with the same name need to be moved to the same directory?

Comment: All the file names under a particular directory for example path with pattern ```ZRT834_9``` are unique. But, the same filenames can be repeated in other paths.

Comment: How should we identify the path component that you want used for your new directories? In the example above the first set matches the fifth item from the left or the second from the right, and the second set matches the seventh item from the left or the second from the right.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is what is making the folder structure more complicated.

Comment: Can you please suggest if we assume the folder structure as uniform across all tar files? @roaima

Comment: If you want to assume that please [edit] your question to make it so

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: Regarding `I have a list of paths stored in a variable tmp` - that's always a bad starting point. Having them stored in and array would be better but chances are you should be reading them from a file or as the output of a command. Ask a new question about that if you'd like help with it.

Comment: Sure, I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes, based on your description, that:

- variable `tmp` contains a newline-separated list of filenames[1]
- you want to extract the **fifth** path element from the filename (e.g. `ZRT834_9` and `ZRT207_1`)
- you want to create a sub-directory with that path element if it doesn't already exist
- you want to symlink the filename into that newly created directory.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

tmp="/abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar
     /abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S2_L001_I1.tar
     /abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar
     /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar
     /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R2.tar
     /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar"

while read -r f ; do
  d="$(echo "$f" | sed -E 's:^(/+[^/]+){4}/+([^/]*)/.*:\2:')"
  [ -z "$d" ]   && echo "Error: no fifth element in path: '$f'" && exit 1
  mkdir -p "$d" || exit 1
  ln -s "$f" "$d/"
done <<< "$tmp"
```

The `sed` script uses Extended Regular Expressions (`-E` option) and (roughly translated into English) captures the first 4 groups (the `{4}`) of `/+[^/]+` (one-or-more slashes followed by one-or-more non-slash characters) into capture group 1, then the next `[^/]+` after one-or-more slashes into capture group two and replaces the entire input line with just capture group two (`\2`).

The "one-or-more slashes" is because it's perfectly valid to have a pathname like `/foo/////////////////bar////baz` - the excess /s will be ignored.  BTW, some programs (e.g. `smbclient`) will interpret the first element of a pathname **beginning** with 2 slashes as a server name prefix, but that's not the case with most programs.

[1] you really should use an array for this.  e.g.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# double-quote each array element even though your sample
# data doesn't need to be quoted - because other filenames
# might contain white-space or shell metacharacters.
tmp=("/abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar"
     "/abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S2_L001_I1.tar"
     "/abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar"
     "/abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar"
     "/abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R2.tar"
     "/abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar")

for f in "${tmp[@]}" ; do
  d="$(echo "$f" | sed -E 's:^(/+[^/]+){4}/+([^/]*)/.*:\2:')"
  [ -z "$d" ]   && echo "Error: no fifth element in path: '$f'" && exit 1
  mkdir -p "$d" || exit 1
  ln -s "$f" "$d/"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining your answer in a very detailed manner. My initial question was a bit more complicated. Is there any way we can generalize the answer where the subdirectory can be subsetted without the assumption of position?. Forex, Without the assumption of the 5th element. I had to edited the question earlier to reduce the complexity.

Comment: sure, you can use a regex to match and extract anything.   the difficulty is in crafting the regex so that it matches exactly what you want and **only** what you want.  You haven't provided any details on exactly what pattern you want to match. Without such details, your question is too broad to answer but I"ll guess `ZRT[^/]+_[^/]+` to match anything beginning with ZRT and containing an underscore followed by some more characters.  To extract that with sed: `sed -E 's:.*/(ZRT[^/]+_[^/]+).*:\1:'`

Comment: The broader question is off-topic here (because it's effectively asking for learning materials) but can be answered with "teach yourself regular expressions".  [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good site to help with that.

Comment: This is a great resource.

Comment: I just realized that this is a better solution compared to any other as it works well in my case. Accepting this as my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`:

```
files=(
  /abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar
  /abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S2_L001_I1.tar
  /abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar
  /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R1.tar
  /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R2.tar
  /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_I2.tar
)
# or files=(${(f)"$(<list.txt)"}) to get the file list from the non-empty
# lines of list.txt, or files=($=tmp) for word splitting the contents
# of a $tmp scalar variable according to the current value of $IFS.

for file ($files) {
  dir=${file:h5:t}
  mkdir -p -- $dir && ln -s -- $file $dir/
}
```

Where `${file:h5}` gets the `5`-component¹ `h`ead of `$file`, and `:t` the tail of the result. Or you could do `${file:t3:h1}` to count from the end.

---

<sup>¹ here *component* being path component. For instance, in `../a//b///c/./d/e`, the components will be `..`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `.`, `d` and `e`. `:h5` would give `../a//b///c/.`, and `:t` would then yield `.`. See also `${file:A:h5:t}` to get a canonical absolute path before applying the `:h5` and `:t`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed has the ability to execute shell commands with parameters from backlinks in a substitution construct:

```
sed 's%.*/\([^/]*/\)[^/]*/[^/]*%mkdir -p "\1";ln -s "&" "\1"%e;d' <<<"$tmp"
```

Comment: I would stay well clear of that `e` flag. First, it runs a shell in addition to those `mkdir` and `ln` command for each line, making it less efficient, you might as well omit the flag and pipe to `sh`. But more importantly, it makes it hard to avoid command injection vulnerabilities. Here you forgot to quote the paths to make it a string in the shell syntax, so for instance, if the dir name is `$(reboot)`, that will reboot.

Comment: I completely agree with your remarks, but the main thing I have shown is that such an opportunity exists and is interesting in itself, thank you. Please do not delete your comment, it will be a good addition.

Comment: Your solution actually works for the question asked. But, if the file structure is different. Would it work?. My initial question was a bit more complicated so I had to ask it as a different [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669049/extract-sub-directory-based-on-matching-pattern-from-path-and-create-symbolic-li) based on suggestions from the community.