# Extract sub-directory based on matching pattern from path and create symbolic links

Tags: bash, text-processing, find

I extracted the paths for files using `find`. The command to `find` paths is as follows:

```bash
tmp=$(find $Some_Dir -name "*.gz")
```

The output is:

```
echo "$tmp"

/xxxx/abc/bcd/def/something/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_R1.gz /xx/abc/bcd/def/ddd/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S2_L001_I1.gz /abc/bcd/def/ZRT834/ZRT834_9/5678/S1_L001_I2.gz /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R1.gz /abc/bcd/def/hfgdh/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_R2.gz /abc/bcd/def/ZRT207/ZRT207_1/5678/S1_L001_I2.gz /sgdj/hbsdj/ldnc/jnjdss/ZRT102_9/S5_L002_I1.gz
```

I want to create a sub-directory based on matching pattern and create symbolic links. For example, I want to match the pattern starting with `ZRT` and ending with `_somenumber` in each path and create sub-directory with that path element if it doesn't exist. Then create symbolic links of the `.gz` files into their respective directories.

The output needs to be: `ZRT834_9` directory with symbolic links of `S1_L001_R1.gz`, `S2_L001_I1.gz`, and `S1_L001_I2.gz` and so on.

Edit: This was my original question. Also, I had posted a less complex question earlier [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669006/extract-sub-directory-name-based-on-pattern).

Comment: I had posted that question earlier. But, based on a few member's suggestions, I had posted this question to specifically address my issue.

Comment: ok, sorry, i misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this immediately in the process of finding files:

```
find Dir/ -name '*.gz' -regex '.*/ZRT[^/]*_[0-9]+/.*' -exec \
bash -c ': "$(grep -o "/ZRT[^/]*_[0-9]\+/" <<<"$0")";\
mkdir -p "${_#/}"; ln -s "$0" "${_#/}"' {} \;
```

Comment: I do not want to do it in the process of finding files as it is dependent on the previous outcome. Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `tmp=$(find $Some_Dir -name "*.gz")`:

1. Always quote your shell variables, i.e. `"$Some_Dir"`, not just `$Some_Dir`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.
2. Don't read file names into a scalar variable as it becomes much harder to deal with spaces in file names if you do, read them into an array.

so that should be:

```
readarray -d '' files < <(find "$Some_Dir" -type f -name '*.gz' -print0)
```

Now you can just loop on the files to do whatever you want, e.g. since you said `I want to match the pattern starting with ZRT and ending with _somenumber`:

```
re='ZRT.*_somenumber'
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $file =~ $re ]]; then
        do whatever you like
    fi
done
```

Obviously you don't NEED the array of files in the first place, you could just loop directly on the output of `find`:

```
re='ZRT.*_somenumber'
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    if [[ $file =~ $re ]]; then
        do whatever you like
    fi
done < <(find "$Some_Dir" -type f -name '*.gz' -print0)
```

Comment: When I pass ```ln -s $file ```  after ```do```. It is giving me the bug.